# How to convert u-law and a-law encoded wav files to pcm wav file in c program?

Tags: c, type-conversion, wav, pcm

I want to convert a-law & u-law wav files to pcm wav file in c program. How do I do that ? Will sox c libraries be useful ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Search for an audio library
2. Get Documentation for that library
3. Search for the terms u-law and a-law
4. If you can't find something meaningful go to step 1.
5. Use this library in your code according to the documentation

**EDIT**

If you follow these steps for the SOX library you'll find the line

> ul indicates μ-law (8-bit), al indicates A-law

which is a strong hint that these formats are supported by sox